# when appending url by $location.url() data does not appear

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when i did not append url with `$location.url('?mobile_no=' + $scope.dash.mobile );` it shows out data successfully but i just wish to change url with above parameter and data should be shown as earlier. to achieve this goal what i have to do?

```
$http.post('http://104.........../get_user_info', dashno).
        success(function(data,status,header,config){
          console.log("data: %j", data);
          if(data.success == 1){
            $location.url('?mobile_no=' + $scope.dash.mobile );
            $scope.showDetails=true;

              $scope.email_id = data.email_id;
              $scope.user_name = data.user_name;
              $scope.default_vpa = data.default_vpa;
              $scope.def_vpa_name = data.def_vpa_name;
              console.log('$scope.email_id'+$scope.email_id);
              ----------------------
              ----------------------
```

Comment: In what context are you using this  $location.url('?mobile_no=' + $scope.dash.mobile );? I mean why do you need that and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i have used `$location.url('?mobile_no=' + $scope.dash.mobile );` so that when we suppose to to press browser back button it should take it out previous route.

Comment: So where does data not appearing?

Comment: You have to sanitize the url, refer this links - 1) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize
2) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize